# Exceptions while deploying activiti-explorer.war in WildFly 8 Cluster

Tags: activiti

When I deploy the activiti-explorer.war in WildFly Cluster, I'm getting the below Exception.
I am using Activiti version 5.19.0.2, Any ideas?

```
ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.OutboundTransferTask] (transport-thread-9) Failed to send entries to node slave:server-two/web : java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure to marshal argument(s): org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure to marshal argument(s)
at org.infinispan.commons.util.Util.rewrapAsCacheException(Util.java:581)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.invokeRemoteCommand(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:176)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.invokeRemotely(JGroupsTransport.java:521)
at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:281)
at org.infinispan.statetransfer.OutboundTransferTask.sendEntries(OutboundTransferTask.java:233)
at org.infinispan.statetransfer.OutboundTransferTask.run(OutboundTransferTask.java:174)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure to marshal argument(s)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.marshallCall(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:333)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.processSingleCall(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:352)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.invokeRemoteCommand(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:167)
... 11 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableException: org.activiti.workflow.simple.converter.json.SimpleWorkflowJsonConverter
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
in field simpleWorkflowJsonConverter
in field application
in field repaintRequestListeners
in object java.util.HashMap@1075666a
in object org.jboss.as.clustering.marshalling.SimpleMarshalledValue@1075666a
in object org.infinispan.container.entries.ImmortalCacheEntry@30172969
in object java.util.ArrayList@30172988
in object org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateChunk@4606824f
in object java.util.ArrayList@e871e7c1
in object org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateResponseCommand@6d997db3
```

Comment: perhaps tell us more detail of your architecture or system for more understand and more helping you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply... I want to deploy Activiti Explorer web app in a cluster environment to achieve High availability and session replication. So, i'm using wildfly two node cluster for this.I downloaded the war file from http://activiti.org/download.html and I didn't change any thing in activiti war file. When i deployed it in single node it is working fine but not with the cluster.